# Shapekeys - Meshes have same number of vertices but still get error "mesh must have same number of vertices"?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, shape-keys

Alright, I had 2 identical meshes and slightly modified the vertices on one. I need to join the other as a shapekey on the first. So I decimated one so it has exactly the same number of faces as the other, as measured by decimate modifier.

[image: deci]

Yet when I do the "Join as shapes" shapekey option, I get the same error  "mesh must have same number of vertices".

I have applied the decimate modifier. What is wrong here?

Comment: Same number of faces doesn't  correlate to same number of verts.

Comment: Ok @batFINGER so how would I get same number of verts to do this?